# How to change the color of the bar that shows up when an Entry is active?

Tags: maui

I'm trying to change the color of the bar that lights up when focusing on an Entry (see screenshot below for reference)

The bar is purple (on google pixel emulator) when I start typing.

[Entry Bar](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NtNM6.png)

`

```
    <Style TargetType="Entry">
        <Setter Property="TextColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Black}, Dark={StaticResource White}}" />
        <Setter Property="BackgroundColor" Value="Transparent" />
        <Setter Property="FontFamily" Value="OpenSansRegular"/>
        <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14" />
        <Setter Property="PlaceholderColor" Value="{AppThemeBinding Light={StaticResource Gray200}, Dark={StaticResource Gray500}}" />
        <Setter Property="MinimumHeightRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="MinimumWidthRequest" Value="44"/>
        <Setter Property="VisualStateManager.VisualStateGroups">
            <VisualStateGroupList>
                <VisualStateGroup x:Name="CommonStates">
                    <VisualState x:Name="Normal"/>
                    <VisualState x:Name="Disabled"/>
                </VisualStateGroup>
            </VisualStateGroupList>
        </Setter>
    </Style>
```

`

- Changed my primary, secondary and tertiary color in styles just in case it is automatically set to one of those
- Tried to set a visual state for "Focused" in the code below under "VisualStateGroup"

Comment: I think no such property could be directly set in the style. You could use a [Customize controls with handlers](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/maui/user-interface/handlers/customize?view=net-maui-7.0)